# Angular 7. Iterate indefinitely among 3 states when clicking (to order a table)

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to order a table in Angular 7, and when I click on the header I want to change between 3 states (asc, desc, disabled). What is the best way to iterate between these 3 states indefinitely in typescript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a variable that holds that state.

`let currentFilter = 0;`

`myState = [asc, desc, disabled];`

and then `(click)="onFilter()"`

with a method `onFilter() { this.currentFilter === 2 ? this.currentFilter = 0 : this.currentFilter += 1 }`

with this, you already have your current state, and on click you iterate over the three.. you could even add it to your markup with `<span>{{ myState[currentFilter] }}</span>`.

On the filtering logic though, you need to create a sorting method, and Idk if you already have that set. you can call it inside the `onFilter()` method and then use the new values.

If you wish to keep everything simplear and cleaner, I'd go with:

```
filter = {
   currentFilter: 0,
   state: [asc, desc, disabled],
   onFilter: this.onFilter // basically putting the onFilter function here
}
```

and then use that object to do the iterations. You could even export it, as a class somewhere, and reuse it anywhere you wish to do filtering.

```
export class TableFilter {
    currentFilter = 0;
    state = [asc, desc, disabled];
    onFilter() { ... };
}
```

and in your component

```
filter = new TableFilter();
```

and then use that

Comment: Great idea Francisco. It works perfectly. Many thanks